# A rebus from a while ago

Tags: rebus

<sup><sup>This is an entry to the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #26](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5794/fortnightly-topic-challenge-26-rebus): [rebus](/questions/tagged/rebus).</sup></sup>

A few years back, I came up with the following. Can you tell me what the picture is about?

[image: A rebus puzzle for you]

A small note for solvers - this does exist elsewhere on the internet, and while I wasn't able to find it on a Google Images search I humbly request that you avoid doing so if you want to find the answer on your own, just in case.

Comment: Are the annotations intended to be part of the puzzle?

Comment: They are. They actually provide a second route to the solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a possibility:

> **Uncertainties**

Explanation:

> As the other answers mentioned, all eight visible pictures represent T's (a tea cup, a golf tee etc.), and although the last three signs are cut off, if we follow the pattern, it would've been another 't + t'. So the **"Answer: Ten T's = Uncertainties"**, even though **all the comments accompanying it are *uncertain* of what everything really is.**

Comment: One thing is certain ... you have the right answer! Congratulations :D

Answer (score 25):

I think the rebus describes ...

> ... **Eighties parties**.

Explanation:

> The centre part without the cut-off symbols shows eight different T's / tees / teas, so eight tees or Eighties. The bottom part shows two partially visible t's, so part-tees or parties. (That doesn't explain why the t's are all different, though.)
>
>  This solution fits with the title: Eighties parties are from a while ago.

Comment: An interesting interpretation! As it happens, "from a while ago" is just a literal description of when I came up with the puzzle, and is not an additional hint.

Answer (score 14):

I'd guess the picture describes a:

> Manatee (many-tee)

What we see is:

> A teacup, a teapot, a capital T, a small t, an italicized t, a golf tee, the character tau, a tee-shirt, etc etc. Given the variation of "t"s being represented I guess there are many-tees.

But this word isn't exactly one I'd consider common-use so I suspect I may be on the wrong track here.

Comment: Not bad. Not right, but definitely a step in the right direction. I think.

Answer (score 13):

Just for varie**T**y, let’s add this up to a case of...

> ...[**teetotalism**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/teetotal)
>  —
>  obtaining a sum total of all kinds of **T**s.
>  
>       =  
>  
>  **T**eacup                      + **T**eapot                 + 
>  capital **T**                   + sans serif lowercase **T** + 
>  italic/script lowercase **T**   + golf **T**ee               + 
>  Greek lowercase **T** (**T**au) + **T**-shirt                + 
>  **T**-top (a type of car roof)  + more ... to infini -**T**

After all, this rebus doesn’t contain a single detectable drop of alcohol.

And “from a while ago,” as in the title?

> [Teetotalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teetotalism)
>  had its heyday in the 19<sup>th</sup> century..

Comment: Cute, but not what I was looking for.